# Shopify runs the same webhook 3-4 times

Tags: php, shopify

My shopify application is running the same webhook 3-4 times everytime I fullfill a new order.

I've inserted header 200 in the top of the code, but shopify can't see it.

Here is my header code:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```

Anyone that knows a solution for this?

Comment: what about http://php.net/manual/it/function.http-response-code.php?

Comment: I've tried that (http_response_code(200))